# ValidationResult to send 409 conflict status code ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, validationattribute

Is it possible to send HttpStatusCode.Conflict(409) from ValidationResult method of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

By default it is returning HttpStatusCode.BadRequest(400). is there any possible way to send different status codes with ValidationResult  method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using asp.net core you can override the ApiController attribute behavior in the StartUp > ConfigureServices

```
services.AddControllers()
                    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
                        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                        {
                            var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(context.ModelState)
                            {
                                Status = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict,                            
                            };

                            return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(problemDetails){};
                        }; });
```

Comment: Thanks @ranton187, It solved the issue. In my case I just changed the UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(problemDetails) to ConflictObjectResult(problemDetails). And it is giving 409 conflict status code

Comment: @SalmanTahir my pleasure